# Flutter Webview - Keyboard does not close automatically

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

The keyboard automatically opens when I click on a input box, but when I press `okay` or elsewhere, the keyboard does not automatically close. How can I hide soft keyboard on losing focus?

```
class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I added the code block below to my code, but it didn't work. Webview remained on the white screen.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Enable hybrid composition.
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gamCw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on an Android emulator?

Try to use Hybrid composition

```
class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Enable hybrid composition.
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> The WebView is relying on Platform Views to embed the Android’s
> webview within the Flutter app. By default a Virtual Display based
> platform view backend is used, this implementation has multiple
> keyboard. When keyboard input is required we recommend using the
> Hybrid Composition based platform views implementation

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/webview_flutter#using-hybrid-composition

Comment: I tried to add this code block. But, it didn't work in any devices. When I switch to another Webview with the navigation bar, the blank page is shown and the web page does not open.